# pandas : clustering values of a Serie using dictionnary's keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm working on a DataFrame, like this one :

```
DF_draft = pd.DataFrame(data={"subdivision_name" : ["01","02","03","04","05"], 
            "day": ["2020-03-18","2020-03-18","2020-03-18","2020-03-18","2020-03-18"],
            "data":[0,11,12,13,2]})

    subdivision_name    day         data
0   01                  2020-03-18  0
1   02                  2020-03-18  11
2   03                  2020-03-18  12
3   04                  2020-03-18  13
4   05                  2020-03-18  2
```

I'm trying to keep a few subdivision_name rows, by following a dictionnary like this :

```
reference_dict = {"Area Alpha": ["01","03","04","15","26","38","42","43","63","69","73","74"], 
                   "Area Beta" : ["21","25","39","58","70","71","89","90"],
                  "Area Gaga" : ["02","01","07","57","88","67","68","54"]}
```

My goal is to put one of several keys of reference_dict in a list, and then using it as an argument of a function. For example, the result for ["Area Alpha"] will be a DF like :

```
Area Alpha   day
25           2020-03-18
```

The key of reference_dict becomes a Serie's name, and we add values of subdivision "01", "03" and "04" that are in reference_dict["Area Alpha"]

I started test with this function :

```
def area_cluster(DF, one_list):
    for area in one_list:
        if area in reference_dict:
            condition = DF["subdivision_name"].any() in reference_dict[area]
            new_DF = DF[condition]
        else:
            print("Wrong orthograph")     
    return new_DF
```

I tested

```
DF = area_cluster(DF_draft, ["Area Alpha"])
```

And got this error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-46075ea2a017> in <module>
----> 1 DF = area_cluster(DF_draft, ["Area Alpha"])

<ipython-input-129-a86847d436dd> in area_cluster(DF, one_list)
      3         if area in subdivision_dict:
      4             condition = DF["subdivision_name"].any() in subdivision_dict[area]
----> 5             new_DF = DF[condition]
      6         else:
      7             print("Wrong orthograph")

c:\users\raphael\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2904             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2905                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2906             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2907             if is_integer(indexer):
   2908                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\users\raphael\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: True
```

Maybe it an indexing problem, but I didn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: What does this means: and we add values of subdivision "01", "03" and "04" that are in reference_dict["Area Alpha"]? Could you add the output for your sample dataframe?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. The sample is like described at the beginning, and I'm trying to code a function that :

- isolates rows where subdivision name are both in a DF and a dictionnary
- then clusters this sudvisions by area => each area tested becomes a Serie, to have one row a day 

So if we consider only "Alpha Area" (which keeps "01", "03","04",... etc values) and we have only in a DF subdivions "01", "03" and "04", the new DF["Alpha Area"] should return 25 (0+12+13) for 2020-03-18

Comment: And you want a df for each key in `reference_dict`?

Comment: One DF for all keys put in one_list would be better !

Comment: Could you have more than one date? BTW please add the expected output for the df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

DF_draft = pd.DataFrame(data={"subdivision_name": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"],
                              "day": ["2020-03-18", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-18"],
                              "data": [0, 11, 12, 13, 2]})

reference_dict = {"Area Alpha": ["01", "03", "04", "15", "26", "38", "42", "43", "63", "69", "73", "74"],
                  "Area Beta": ["21", "25", "39", "58", "70", "71", "89", "90"],
                  "Area Gaga": ["02", "01", "07", "57", "88", "67", "68", "54"]}


def area_cluster(df, one_list):
    ss = []
    for area in one_list:
        if area in reference_dict:
            r = df.assign(area=df["subdivision_name"].map(dict.fromkeys(reference_dict[area], area)))
            r = r.dropna().groupby(['area', 'day'])['data'].sum().reset_index()
            ss.append(r)

    return pd.concat(ss, ignore_index=True)


res = area_cluster(DF_draft, ['Area Alpha', "Area Beta", "Area Gaga"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
         area         day  data
0  Area Alpha  2020-03-18    25
1   Area Gaga  2020-03-18    11
```

Comment: very nice solution with `dict.fromkeys` which is much more elegant than my dict reversal, so +1